# excel function ARBEITSTAG not working in English version of Excel

Tags: windows, vba, excel, excel-formula

I have PC with German operating system and MS Excel installation. On this PC I have created Excel Workbook which contains different Excel Worksheet functions.

Then I have second PC with English operating system and MS Excel installation. When I open this Excel Workbook on the PC with English operating system all the Worksheet functions are translated correctly into English versions but the function `ARBEITSTAG` appears like `#NAME?`.

Am I missing something here? How can I bring Excel to use English version of this function as well?

[image]

---

*Notes:*

- The source Excel Workbook doesn't contain VBA code.
- No such a name like `ARBEITSTAG` is defined in this workbook.
- So finally I had to replace the text `ARBEITSTAG` manually with `WORKDAY`.
- With sample workbook with one sheet the formula `ARBEITSTAG` was translated correctly into English version `WORKDAY` so there must be *something* but I was not able to find out what.

Comment: Try WORKDAY(...)

Comment: What does the `ARBEITSTAG` function _do_?

Comment: @Jeeped yes I could overwrite it myself and WORKDAY would do the job, but the Workbook is big and would like to know if there is some possibility how Excel can do it like it does with the other functions.

Comment: @ashleedawg it means workday.

Comment: @NineBerry see edited question, I have added picture, OK?

Comment: @NineBerry I do not enter German name in English version. I create Excel workbook in German OS and _then_ I open this workbook in Excel on English OS. All the worksheet functions which I entered as German are correctly translated into English with exception of `AREBEITSTAG`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the solution you are waiting for, but quite a working one for the English version:

```
Public Function ARBEITSTAG(startDate As Date, days As Long, _
                        Optional holiday As Long = 0) As Date

    ARBEITSTAG = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(startDate, days, holiday)

End Function
```

Comment: beat ya to it :-)

Comment: @ashleedawg - but you have put something about a `Null` which was not working :)

Comment: ...edited that out _just seconds_ before your post...  :-)

Comment: @ashleedawg - well I would not bet on the seconds. However, I cannot see a timestamp of the edit. :)

Comment: ...interesting, I guess I edited so quickly after posting that it counted it at the post time.  So, looks like an _official_ 17 second lead to me :-)

Comment: Here, maybe [these](https://www.typing.com/typinggames) will help you narrow the gap next time...   (kidding!)  :-)~

Comment: @ashleedawg - I have probably slowed down because of the `_` in the parameters - did not want to put it with a scroller.

Comment: ah yes, + since I can see how that could take a while.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could just add a custom function to call the worksheet function by its German name, something like:

```
Public Function Arbeitstag(start_date As Date, days As Variant)
    Arbeitstag = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(start_date, days)
End Function
```